# prevent caching of xmlhttp request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, caching

I have a javascript that retrieves a JSON through an ajax request. My problem is that the browser starts caching the response to this request, so I don't actually get the latest data from the server, but instead an older cached version.

```
    $.getJSON( self.data('pathAllGet'), function( json ) {
        self.data('galleryData',json);
        self.data(render(self));
    });
```

Comment: Use  `cache: false` in your ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `getJSON` method. It is a convenience function for common use cases that don't cover your needs.

Use `ajax` instead. That allows you to include cache busting.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: self.data('pathAllGet'),
  success: function( json ) {
    self.data('galleryData',json);
    self.data(render(self));
  },
  cache: false
});
```

By adding `cache: false`, you tell jQuery to append a uniqueish string to the URL. This means that next time you request the data, you'll get a different URL which the browser won't have in its cache.

Alternatively, set up your [caching rules on the server](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).